# UISearchController Scope Bar (Instagram's way)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

I am currently recreating an Instagram app. (For learning purposes.)

But I am stuck recreating the search bar in the Search page. 
[Instagram's Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CncbB.png)

So far my implementation of UISearchController displays a segment controller with buttons. But is not close to Instagrams. Or any other animation similar to it that will lead me on the right direction will be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/Hareesh123/MGSwipeTabBarController12) works for copying that kind of tab view controller. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mgswipetabbar&safe=strict&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS654US654&hl=en-US&biw=375&bih=591&prmd=mvin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTtKbhkpDOAhUELmMKHVRmBKMQ_AUICSgD#safe=strict&hl=en-US&tbm=isch&q=mgswipetabbarcontroller&imgrc=HflLmpIlAeXEoM%3A) is a picture of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Github [page](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu). They have created a segmented controller just like instagram's, and if you scroll down you can see images of it.